# [obj.keyframe_insert, bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].lifetime]; how to insert keyframe to an existed particle setting, e.g lifetime

Tags: python, particles

I am trying to randomize some values of selected objects in blender
How can I keyframe_instert of the active particle properties?
I can do it with clicking "I" of the desired area and it works (creates a keyframe)

I tried: (n

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].lifetime')
obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="lifetime")
```

gave type errors both

```
TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "lifetime" not found
```

[image: n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set on the object that has the property**

Python console code.  A default particle system has been added to a Plane that has context.

The lifetime is set to 10 and keyframed on frame 1.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Plane']

>>> ps = C.object.particle_systems['ParticleSettings'].settings
>>> ps
bpy.data.particles['ParticleSettings']

>>> ps.lifetime
10.0

>>> ps.keyframe_insert("lifetime", frame=1)
True
```

Notice the objects particle systems settings points to its data item in  `bpy.data.particles` which is the ID object that the action (typically `bpy.data.actions['ParticleSettingsAction']`) will belong to.

Comment: thank you so much. I don't know why there is an additional setting I need to add to the end. It does not require it for modifiers.